# Constrain the table size to a limited area

Tags: uitableview, size

How to constrain the table size to a limited area in a view 
The Methods to be used ?

Comment: Can you please explain the question.

Comment: Yeah.. If you want part of the view to be tableview.. Anyhow, I found my way out...

Comment: UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 190, 320, 143) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    //tableView.bounds
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];